# Unable to login to Gnome (-> login loop), only Unity login possible

Tags: unity, gnome, login-screen

I have a problem basically exactly the same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614402/unable-to-login-to-gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-14-04) one.

What did I do? I wanted to try out GNOME and installed it according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577093/how-to-install-gnome-desktop) guide:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then after a reboot I ended up at the lightdm login screen and had in addition to the unity option the additional GNOME and GNOME (Classic) options available. Just as intended I suppose! Although, I am only able to  login with unity (everything working fine in that regard), but when I try to login with GNOME or GNOME (Classic) I get stuck in the login loop described in the aforementioned post: After password input screen turns dark for a few seconds, I see my usual desktop background for a brief moment, and then get transported back to the login screen without any error message.

I basically googled and tried everything there is with connection to login loop, but nothing worked. The post mentioned above is the only one with exactly the same problem as mine that I could find though (login with unity possible, but with GNOME not).

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Since I already tried everything I could find, I really need some out-of-the-box thinking here. What could be the problem? I am not totally new to Linux, but far away from being an expert. Please be so kind to consider that with your answers.

Is there maybe another (correct) way to install the GNOME desktop? Did I make any mistakes with the installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I do not know why it stopped working. Check if you can  install wayland session.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-wayland
```

After that in login screen you can select "GNOME on wayland".
It resolved my problem and at this moment I didn't see any difference in use.

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz Bazan, I will try it out, as soon as I can. But at the moment I put up completely new system for testing. I will definitely let you know if this solution works as soon as possible. To be clear: Now you are able to sign in with both, unity and GNOME?

Comment: Im not using unity, but I can login on plasma, mate and gnome (only wayland).